# How can I pass an array into an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $('#form').serialize() + "&p=1"
}
```

I also need to pass this array:

```
cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

How can I pass `cars` in that ajax call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$('#form').serialize() + "&p=1&cars=" + JSON.stringify(cars)
```

---

Based on how that string will look like, one might also need to use e.g. [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
$('#form').serialize() + "&p=1&cars=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(cars))
```

---

Updated based on a comment

The reverse of `JSON.stringify()` is [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Also for my information, is there any js/jQuery function which converts an json string to an array?

Comment: @MartinAJ `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @MartinAJ Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass within new key

```
data: {form: $('#form').serialize() + "&p=1", cars: '["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]'}
```